# how to say "change from an old job to a new one"

Tags: preposition

I wish to inform someone about a job change. Should I say:

- von der Firma x **zur** neuen Firma Y **OR**
- von der Firma x **auf die neue** / **auf der neuen** Firma Y ?

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely the first version.
If the name of the company is known to the person you are talking to, you could also omit "der Firma" and just say the name

> Ich bin von Siemens zu BMW gewechselt.

Answer (score 2):

Your second suggestion(s) is (are) wrong.

The wording is somewhat dependent on who and when you want to inform about the change e.g has the change already taken place or is it intended as an announcement? I'd suggest:

> Ich werde zum 01.01.2020 von VW zu Mercedes wechseln.
>
> Ich werde zum 01.01.2020 von meiner bisherigen Firma X zu Firma Y wechseln.
>
> Ich bin von VW zu Mercedes gewechselt.
>
> Ich bin am 01.11.2019 von VW zu Mercedes [als Verkaufsleiter] gewechselt.

---

> I will change from VW to Mercedes on 01.01.2020.
>
> I will change from my previous company X to company Y on 01.01.2020.
>
> I have changed from VW to Mercedes.
>
> I changed from VW to Mercedes [as sales manager] on 01.11.2019.

Comment: From a typographical point of view, the leading zeros in the dates should be omitted. Written text is no Excel-table, so a more elegant way is to write 1. Januar 2020 or at least 1.1.2020.

Comment: This is not quite correct. I just read about date formatting in German here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datumsformat#DIN_5008 . As following this DIN rule, the leading zeros can only be omitted when the month is not numeric.

Comment: @MarkLösche: Die Schlussfolgerung scheint mir anhand einer verkürzten Sekundärquelle wie der Wikipedia doch etwas gewagt. Das zulässige *gewohnte Format* bietet doch einigen Spielraum...